# SQL to Count Records that Existed by Decade

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

I have an Oracle a table that has 3 columns. FILE_NUM, START_DATE, END_DATE. FILE_NUM is a unique identifier and so each row is unique.

| FILE_NUM | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | Apr. 04, 1977 | Jun. 30, 1984 |
| 1112 | Jan. 03, 1987 | Sep. 05, 2010 |
| 1113 | May. 14, 1962 | Jan. 30, 1998 |
| 1114 | Oct. 09, 2001 | Aug. 22, 2025 |
| 1113 | May. 14, 1962 | Jan. 30, 1998 |
| 1114 | Nov. 18, 2003 | Aug. 22, 2028 |
| etc |  |  |

I want to query a count of files that existed per decade. Something like:

| Decade | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1960-1969 | 10 |
| 1970-1979 | 25 |
| 1980-1989 | 42 |

The logic is, if the file existed at any point in any decade, count it in each of those decades. So for file_num 1112, it should get counted in the 1980's, 1990's, 2000's, and 2010's.

I don't even know if this is possible. I've tinkered around in my query a few times, but I'm not sure I know enough functions or technique to get this sort of result.

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

I should clarify how the counts will be made. I need to approach the date ranges in 3 ways in order to capture which file_nums existed within each decade.

1. If it started between the decade range, count it.
2. If it ended between the decade range, count it.
3. If it started before the decade range and ended after the decade range, count it.

I crafted up the following SQL. I am still trying to figure out if it's doing what I want it to do. If anyone has suggestion

```
with decades as
  (
  select
    concat(concat(floor(extract(year from t.start_date)/10)*10, '-'), floor(extract(year from t.start_date)/10)*10 + 9) DECADE
  from 
    table t
  group by
    concat(concat(floor(extract(year from t.start_date)/10)*10, '-'), floor(extract(year from t.start_date)/10)*10 + 9)
  )

select
  count(a.file_num),
  decades.decade
from
  table a,
  decades
where 
  extract(year from a.start_date) between extract(year from to_date(SUBSTR(decades.decade,0,4), 'YYYY')) and extract(year from to_date(SUBSTR(decades.decade,6,9), 'YYYY'))
  or
  extract(year from a.end_date) between extract(year from to_date(SUBSTR(decades.decade,0,4), 'YYYY')) and extract(year from to_date(SUBSTR(decades.decade,6,9), 'YYYY'))
  or
  (extract(year from a.start_date) < extract(year from to_date(SUBSTR(decades.decade,0,4), 'YYYY'))
   and
   extract(year from a.end_date) > extract(year from to_date(SUBSTR(decades.decade,6,9), 'YYYY'))
  )  
group by
  decades.decade
order by
  decades.decade
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also take advantage of the connect by clause to do that.
I assume you don't have any duplicate rows (these columns **FILE_NUM, START_DATE, END_DATE** should be unique) in your real data.

```sql
SELECT dec_start, dec_end, COUNT(*) nb
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, level
      , 10 * trunc( extract ( year from (START_DATE) ) / 10 ) + 10 * LEVEL - 10 dec_start
      , 10 * trunc( extract ( year from (START_DATE) ) / 10 ) + 10 * LEVEL - 1 dec_end
    FROM YourTable T
    CONNECT BY 
        10 * TRUNC( EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM (START_DATE) ) / 10 ) + 10 * LEVEL - 10 
            <   10 * CEIL( EXTRACT ( YEAR FROM (END_DATE) ) / 10 )
    AND PRIOR FILE_NUM = FILE_NUM
    AND PRIOR START_DATE = START_DATE
    AND PRIOR END_DATE = END_DATE
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
)
group by dec_start, dec_end 
order by dec_start, dec_end
;
```

[demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1daea9cae72594aa6ca2b0a4cb687e1b)

Comment: This is great. I have little experience using 'connect by prior' so I did some more research. I think this example with my data helps me visualize the query better. I'm getting identical numbers as my query above, but this one is much more efficient and faster running. I made some adjustments to concatenate the decades ranges into one column via: 

"concat(concat(decade_start, '-'), decade_end) decade"

But everything else works as I need. Thanks for this.

Comment: One more point of clarification to answer your point and for future readers. Yes, my rows are unique. The FILE_NUM is a unique identifier. I will update that in my question.

Comment: Glad to see I could help. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pull something together by casting the year of the date divided by 10 to an integer, then multiplying that by 10.  Example...

```
2019 / 10 = 201.9 cast as integer = 201 * 10 = 2010
```

Then, add 9 years to above for the ending year

```
2019 + 10 = 2029 / 10 = 202.9 cast as integer = 202 * 10 = 2020 + 9 = 2029
```

So, all you should care about is the beginning date in question... something like

```
select
      concat( cast( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM m.start_date ) / 10 as int ) * 10, 
             concat( '-', 
             cast( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM m.start_date ) / 10 as int ) * 10 + 9)),
      count(*) as NumRecs
   from
      table m
   group by 1
```

Comment: I think that's getting close, however maybe I need to explain what needs to be counted. The file needs to exist within the decade so I believe I need to approach the date ranges in 3 ways. 1. If it started between the decade range, count it. 2. If it ended during the decade range, count it. 3. if it started before the decade range and ended after the decade range, count it. I'll update my post to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

best option could be have a decade dimension table:

[image]

And do join with main table:

```
select d.decade, 
       count(file_num) as count 
  from table m
  join decade d
    on m.start_date >= d.decade_start_date
  join decade d2
    on m.end_date <= d2.decade_end_date
 where 1 = 1
   and d.decade = d2.decade 
 group by 1
```